# It's a Bit of a Stretch․․․

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, integer, binary

### Input:

We take two inputs:

- An input `b` with two distinct values: `Left` and `Right`.*†*
- And a positive integer `n`.

### Output:

Based on the Left/Right input, we output either of the following two sequences in the range of `1-n` (in the sequences below the first 125 items are displayed):

```
Left:
1, 6, 7, 56, 57, 62, 63, 960, 961, 966, 967, 1016, 1017, 1022, 1023, 31744, 31745, 31750, 31751, 31800, 31801, 31806, 31807, 32704, 32705, 32710, 32711, 32760, 32761, 32766, 32767, 2064384, 2064385, 2064390, 2064391, 2064440, 2064441, 2064446, 2064447, 2065344, 2065345, 2065350, 2065351, 2065400, 2065401, 2065406, 2065407, 2096128, 2096129, 2096134, 2096135, 2096184, 2096185, 2096190, 2096191, 2097088, 2097089, 2097094, 2097095, 2097144, 2097145, 2097150, 2097151, 266338304, 266338305, 266338310, 266338311, 266338360, 266338361, 266338366, 266338367, 266339264, 266339265, 266339270, 266339271, 266339320, 266339321, 266339326, 266339327, 266370048, 266370049, 266370054, 266370055, 266370104, 266370105, 266370110, 266370111, 266371008, 266371009, 266371014, 266371015, 266371064, 266371065, 266371070, 266371071, 268402688, 268402689, 268402694, 268402695, 268402744, 268402745, 268402750, 268402751, 268403648, 268403649, 268403654, 268403655, 268403704, 268403705, 268403710, 268403711, 268434432, 268434433, 268434438, 268434439, 268434488, 268434489, 268434494, 268434495, 268435392, 268435393, 268435398, 268435399, 268435448, 268435449

Right:
1, 4, 7, 32, 39, 56, 63, 512, 527, 624, 639, 896, 911, 1008, 1023, 16384, 16415, 16864, 16895, 19968, 19999, 20448, 20479, 28672, 28703, 29152, 29183, 32256, 32287, 32736, 32767, 1048576, 1048639, 1050560, 1050623, 1079296, 1079359, 1081280, 1081343, 1277952, 1278015, 1279936, 1279999, 1308672, 1308735, 1310656, 1310719, 1835008, 1835071, 1836992, 1837055, 1865728, 1865791, 1867712, 1867775, 2064384, 2064447, 2066368, 2066431, 2095104, 2095167, 2097088, 2097151, 134217728, 134217855, 134225792, 134225919, 134471680, 134471807, 134479744, 134479871, 138149888, 138150015, 138157952, 138158079, 138403840, 138403967, 138411904, 138412031, 163577856, 163577983, 163585920, 163586047, 163831808, 163831935, 163839872, 163839999, 167510016, 167510143, 167518080, 167518207, 167763968, 167764095, 167772032, 167772159, 234881024, 234881151, 234889088, 234889215, 235134976, 235135103, 235143040, 235143167, 238813184, 238813311, 238821248, 238821375, 239067136, 239067263, 239075200, 239075327, 264241152, 264241279, 264249216, 264249343, 264495104, 264495231, 264503168, 264503295, 268173312, 268173439, 268181376, 268181503, 268427264, 268427391
```

**How are these sequences generated you ask?**

A default sequence from 1 through `n=10` would be:

```
As integer:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

As binary:
1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 1010
```

When we stretch left, the binary will become this:

```
1, 110, 111, 111000, 111001, 111110, 111111, 1111000000, 1111000001, 1111000110
```

Why? The last bit is used once; the single-last is used twice; the second-last is used three times; etc.

```
So `1010` will become (spaces added as clarification): `1111 000 11 0`
```

And these new left-stretched binary strings are converted back to integers:

```
1, 6, 7, 56, 57, 62, 63, 960, 961, 966
```

---

As for stretched right, the first bit is used once; second twice; third three times; etc. Like this:

```
As binary:
1, 100, 111, 100000, 100111, 111000, 111111, 1000000000, 1000001111, 1001110000

As integer:
1, 4, 7, 32, 39, 56, 63, 512, 527, 624
```

### Challenge rules:

- *†* You can take any two distinct values, but state which one you use. So it can be `1/0`, `true/false`, `null/undefined`, `"left"/"right"`, etc.
- `n` is always larger than 0.
- You should support a maximum output of at least your language's default integer (which is 32-bit for most languages).
- Output format is flexible. Can be printed or returned as array/list. Can be with a space, comma, pipe, and alike as delimiter. Your call. (Again, please state what you've used.)

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

Comment: Would you consider accepting bitwise-based answers that can only support `n < 128`, so that the results fit in 32-bit integers?

Comment: @Arnauld Been doubting about it, but since you asked, why not. Will change the rules for 1000 max to what fits for your language's integer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Would still recommend limiting that to at least 16 bits - there's at least one language out there that supports only a single bit as a data type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
BmxJ$mḄð€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98pt8JLJffhjpbDGx41rfn//7@hkel/XUMA)

`-1` for left, `1` for right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>102</s> 96 bytes

```python
lambda d,n:[int(''.join(c*-~i for i,c in enumerate(bin(x+1)[2:][::d]))[::d],2)for x in range(n)]
```

-1 for left, 1 for right

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxDsIgFIXh3ae4G1ylxjKS@CTIQFtoMe2lIZjUxVdHWp3O8P056ztPkWTx90eZ7dINFgZBSgfKnLHrMwbi/bn5BPAxQRA9BAJHr8Ulmx3vKm@XFrVURis1GMRjhMS93/Y6WRodJzRlTfUW2Ox8VgBMgOdNK0De8PSnFMap2kE/KV8)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*

```
LbεIiRƶRëƶ}JC
```

`1` for left.
`0` (or anything else) for right.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJ@ncVs/MoGPbgg6vPrat1sv5/39LLkMA)

**Explanation**

```
L                # push range [1 ... first_input]
 b               # convert to binary
  ε              # apply to each
   Ii            # if second_input is true
     RƶR         # reverse, multiply each element with its 1-based index and reverse again
        ëƶ       # else, multiply each element with its 1-based index
          }      # end if
           J     # join
            C    # convert to base-10
```

Comment: You can use `ε` for -1: `LbεIiRƶRëƶ}JC`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Nice idea using `ë`. Gets around the issue of `if` in an apply in this case :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

`0` for "left", `1` for "right". (It can actually take any falsey or truthy values in place of those 2.)

```
õÈ¤ËpV©EÄªEnFlÃn2
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9ciky3BWqUXEqkVuRmzDbjI=&input=MTAKMA==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integers `U` & `V`.

```
õ
```

Create an array of integers from 1 to `U`, inclusive.

```
È
```

Pass each through a function.

```
¤
```

Convert the current integer to a binary string

```
Ë           Ã
```

Map over the string, passing each character through a function, where `E` is the current index and `F` is the full string.

```
p
```

Repeat the current character

```
V©  ª
```

`©` is logical AND (`&&`) and `ª` is logical OR `||`, so here we're checking if `V` is truthy (non-zero) or not.

```
YÄ
```

If `V` is truthy then `X` gets repeated `Y+1` times.

```
YnZl
```

If `V` is falsey then `X` gets repeated `Y` subtracted from (`n`) the length (`l`) of `Z` times.

```
n2
```

Convert back to a base 10 integer.

Implicitly output resulting array.

Comment: I got down to 16 before realizing it was "first n items" rather than "nth item", so this isn't that bad :P

Comment: @ETHproductions: you weren't the only one to make that mistake ;)

Answer (score 3):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
mȯḋṠṘo?ḣṫ⁰Lḋḣ
```

That's a lot of dotted letters...

Takes first `b` (`0` for left and `1` for right), then `n`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fE@oc7uh/uXPBw54x8@4c7Fj/cufpR4wYfkOCOxf///zf8b2gAAA)

### Explanation

```
mȯḋṠṘo?ḣṫ⁰Lḋḣ  Inputs b=1 and n=5 (implicit).
            ḣ  Range to n: [1,2,3,4,5]
mȯ             Map function over the range:
                 Argument: number k=5
           ḋ     Binary digits: [1,0,1]
   ṠṘ            Repeat each digit with respect to the list
     o    L      obtained by applying to the length (3) the function
      ?  ⁰       if b is truthy
       ḣ         then increasing range: [1,2,3]
        ṫ        else decreasing range: [3,2,1].
                 We get [1,0,0,1,1,1].
  ḋ              Convert back to integer: 39
               Final result [1,4,7,32,39], implicitly print.
```

Comment: You could probably choose to take as `b` directly ḣ or ṫ, saving you three bytes :)

Comment: @Leo Hmm, that's kind of a slippery slope. I could also take one of two versions of the whole program as `b` and have my solution be just `I`...

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 15 bytes

```
⟪¤bw¦¤;ċ%×†_b⟫¦
```

Uses `-1` for left and `1` for right.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9nYWlh///in6rCpGJ3wqbCpDvEiyXDl@KAoF9i4p@rwqb//zIwCjE)

#### Explanation

```
⟪¤bw¦¤;ċ%×†_b⟫¦  Map this block over the range 1..n, with direction as an extra parameter:
 ¤                Swap, bring current number to the top
  b               List of binary digits
   w¦             Wrap each in a list
     ¤            Bring direction to the top
      ;ċ          Push the range 1..len(binary digts)
        %         Select every direction-th element of it (-1 reverses, 1 does nothing)
         ×†       Element-wise repetition
           _      Flatten
            b     Convert from binary to decimal
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 79 bytes

```python
n=>d=>[int(''.join(b[x]*[l-x,x-1][d]for x:2..(l=len(b=bin(i)))),2)for i:1..n+1]
```

`0` is left, `1` is right.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoAgEAC/0s3dyiU9BttHxEuYYMga0sHfm811hnlqeYv0yF34CHy4JC8oRXdJAqdrfnZZt7Vp413wsdSp7ZYIMudrBHyOLOFgtfjbtBsiWYzvT/1XEeyGYBD7Bw)

#### Ungolfed

```python
f=n=>d=>                        # Curried function
[                               # Collect the results in a list
 int(                           # Convert from a binary string to an int:
  ''.join(                       # Join together
   b[x]                           # Each character of the binary string of n
   *[l-x,x-1][d]                  # Repeated by its index or its index from the end, depending on d
   for x:2..(l=len(b=bin(i))))    
 ,2)
 for i:1..n+1                   # Do this for everything from 1 to n inclusive
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>192</s> 187 + 23 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38550/thelethalcoder)*

```cs
b=>n=>new int[n].Select((_,a)=>{var g=Convert.ToString(a+1,2);return(long)g.Reverse().SelectMany((x,i)=>Enumerable.Repeat(x,b?i+1:g.Length-i)).Select((x,i)=>x>48?Math.Pow(2,i):0).Sum();})
```

Byte count also includes:

```cs
namespace System.Linq{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFda@MwEHz3r9jLQyMRVyTlHkpduxylLeUSKE2hD6UcirqxBYqUk@R8UPLbc5LdpjG9xZjV7mh2ZyTcqTAW97WTuoTp1nlcsGujFAovjXbsDjVaKbJE8wW6JRf4iRpL/Td5TyCEUNw5@NXkbSWG89xLASsj32DCpSb00PoCxbittbicGaPSNpXap3B/o@sFWj5TeKmMLouigDnk@1le6PDhGgLsRb@yKcZlCfmTcpoX7ytuocyvjV6h9ezJTL0N0ggfjNIzmln0tdUkEtKSPWIAOST0g2TC9ZaQTSoD0df4AFsi96E@u5KD0UXJxqhLX51KSg/T20ub4uf51YT7ij2YNTkLtYthwNQLQrMd3R@LzpKOB65ZM2ha1j7rdNaVVAiENC3IIUhzptmKv4U3CNtT@JGDrpWCk5OWIRZ6Pdrh6XoeI1rllkpG1uYam8YT6af9FPrQp@y5QotkA3kBmw/OYOlYOh8EfeObk/iI7IFHTxvil@ErpWFz3ymOQvFAw26NveGiaqd8inu20sfBA@hBj/5nVgfY2tAF7br@Hrv2G7fH6F3S/nd7b2uE0TCZc@Vi8g8)

Input: `left` is `true`, `right` is `false`

Explanation:

```cs
b => n =>                                   // Take two inputs (bool and int)
    new int[n].Select((_, a) => {           // Create new collection the size of n
        var g = Convert.ToString(a + 1, 2); // Take every number in sequence 1..n and convert to base 2 (in a string)
        return (long)g.Reverse()            // Reverse the bits
               .SelectMany((x, i) =>        // Replace every bit with a collection of its repeats, then flatten the result
                   Enumerable.Repeat(x, b ? i + 1 : g.Length - i))
               .Select((x, i) => x > 48 ? Math.Pow(2, i) : 0)
               .Sum();                      // Replace every bit with a corresponding power of 2, then sum
    })
```

Comment: https://tio.run/##bVHva9swEP3uv@KWD41EXZGUfRh17TJKO8YSKMugH0oZinuxBYqUSXJ@UPK3Zye7TWO2w5jT3dO7e0@lvyitw0PjlalgtvMBl@LWao1lUNZ48Q0NOlVmiZFL9CtZ4jtqosyf5DUBilJL7@Frm3eVGD7IoEpYW/UCU6kM48fWByjGfWPK67m1Ou1SZUIK3@9Ms0Qn5xqvtTVVURSwgPwwzwtDH26AYE/mWcwwLsvY71TyvHhdSwdVfmvNGl0Qv@wsOJLGZHrJM4ehcYZFOl6Jn0gQj4y/UUyl2TG2TRXRfAwn2AploPr8Rp2PryoxQVOF@kJxfpzdXdoWn7/cTGWoxYPdsEuqXY0I0ywZz/b8cCo5S3oO@HZJUrRqQtbrbGqlERhrW5ADCfO23Uq@0AvQ9hw@5WAareHsrGOIhcGA93j6jseIRvmVVpG1vSZm8cSG6TCFIQy5eKzRIdtCXsD2jZMMnSgfSNA/fAsWn1A8yOhpS/w0euacNg@94piKRxpxb92dLOtuyru4R6dCHHwOAxjw/8zqATsb@qB9399T137g7hS9T7r//hBcgzAeJQupfUz@Ag

Comment: 185 + 23 ^ (was too long in one comment)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Thank you! Unfortunately though, it's 187 since we need to add 1 to the index since it starts at 0, and the sequence starts at 1.

Comment: Isn't `using System.Linq;` shorter than `namespace System.Linq{}`, or am I missing something here? Long time ago I programmed in .NET tbh..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen this uses `Math` and `Convert` both of which are in the `System` namespace, so going for `namespace System.Linq` is the shortest - it allows for using both `System` and `System.Linq` classes.

Comment: Is the `Reverse()` necessary? If you remove it can't you just flip the ternary?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder then the `Math.Pow(2,i)` stops working correctly, and to work again you would either need to get the length after `SelectMany` or add another ternary next to `i`, both of which are longer. Unless I am missing another possibility.

Comment: Ah I missed that part then!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 113 bytes

Oh, this is just far too long! This is what happens when you spend the day writing "real" JavaScript, kiddies; you forget how to golf properly!

Uses any truthy or falsey values for `b`, with `false` being "left" and `true` being "right".

```js
n=>b=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>eval("0b"+[...s=(++e).toString(2)].map((x,y)=>x.repeat(b?++y:s.length-y)).join``),e=0)
```

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
n=>b=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>eval("0b"+[...s=(++e).toString(2)].map((x,y)=>x.repeat(b?++y:s.length-y)).join``),e=0)
)(i.value=10)(j.value=1);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)(+j.value)
```

```css
label,input{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px;height:20px;line-height:20px;vertical-align:middle}input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:100px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>Size: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>Direction: </label><input id=j min=0 max=1 type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 131 bytes

This is significantly longer than [Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139572/58563), but I wanted to try a purely bitwise approach.

Due to the 32-bit limit of JS bitwise operations, this works only for ***n < 128***.

Takes input in currying syntax `(n)(r)`, where ***r*** is falsy for left / truthy for right.

```js
n=>r=>[...Array(n)].map((_,n)=>(z=n=>31-Math.clz32(n),g=n=>n&&(x=z(b=n&-n),r?2<<z(n)-x:b*2)-1<<x*(r?2*z(n)+3-x:x+1)/2|g(n^b))(n+1))
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
n => r => [...Array(n)]       // given n and r
  .map((_, n) => (            // for each n in [0 .. n - 1]
    z = n =>                  //   z = helper function returning the
      31 - Math.clz32(n),     //       0-based position of the highest bit set
    g = n =>                  //   g = recursive function:
      n && (                  //     if n is not equal to 0:
        x = z(b = n & -n),    //       b = bitmask of lowest bit set / x = position of b
        r ?                   //       if direction = right:
          2 << z(n) - x       //         use 2 << z(n) - x
        :                     //       else:
          b * 2               //         use b * 2
      ) - 1                   //       get bitmask by subtracting 1
      << x * (                //       left-shift it by x multiplied by:
        r ?                   //         if direction = right:
          2 * z(n) + 3 - x    //           2 * z(n) + 3 - x
        :                     //         else:
          x + 1               //           x + 1
      ) / 2                   //       and divided by 2
      | g(n ^ b)              //     recursive call with n XOR b
    )(n + 1)                  //   initial call to g() with n + 1
  )                           // end of map()
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>r=>[...Array(n)].map((_,n)=>(z=n=>31-Math.clz32(n),g=n=>n&&(x=z(b=n&-n),r?2<<z(n)-x:b*2)-1<<x*(r?2*z(n)+3-x:x+1)/2|g(n^b))(n+1))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(10)(false)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(10)(true)))
```

Comment: OK, I feel a little better about the length of mine now, seeing as you went for a longer solution, rather than a shorter one.

Comment: "_(pending on OP's approval)._" Approved :) +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 23 bytes

```
{2⊥b/⍨⌽⍣⍺⍳≢b←2⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵}¨⍳
```

left is `1` right is `0` (passed in as left argument of function)

`⍳` is index generator

`{`...`}¨` apply function in braces to each item on the right

`b←2⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵` b is ⍵ encoded as binary (using the inverse of decode to get the minimum number of bits required to represent `⍵` in base 2)

`⍳≢b` generate indexes for vector b (`≢b` is length of b)

`⌽⍣⍺` reverse `⍺` times (used conditionally here for left or right stretch)

`b/⍨` b replicated by (replicates the bits as per the (reverse)index)

`2⊥` decode from base 2

[TryAPL online](http://tryapl.org/?a=0%7B2%u22A5b/%u2368%u233D%u2363%u237A%u2373%u2262b%u21902%u22A5%u2363%AF1%u22A2%u2375%7D%A8%u237310&run)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
B€xJṚ⁹¡$$€Ḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/pUdOaCq@HO2c9atx5aKGKCpD7cEfL////DQ3@GwIA)

Argument #1: `n`
Argument #2: `1` for left, `0` for right.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 111 bytes

```
\d+
$*
1
$`1¶
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
.
$.%`$*R$&$.%'$*L
+s`(R?)(\d)(L?)(.*¶\1\3)$
$2$2$4
¶*[RL]

1
01
+`10
011
%`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxDkIxDEN3nyMf2lSqGmDnAp26EqQgfQYWBmBD/1o9QC9WgjzYluX3un8ez9ucuiYQQ0AmoyNZkBTV61e2giK@ZFBejLjRzsOeuCK9LbRzDLrGUN0zj66ix0igg@uE0fnS6hX@d0gy@cMEi8mcUtoP) Takes the number and either `L` or `R` as a suffix (or on a separate line). Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
1
$`1¶
```

Convert from decimal to unary and count from 1 to `n`.

```
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
```

Convert from unary to binary.

```
.
$.%`$*R$&$.%'$*L
```

Wrap each bit in `R` and `L` characters according to its position in the line.

```
+s`(R?)(\d)(L?)(.*¶\1\3)$
$2$2$4
```

Replace the relevant `R` or `L` characters with the appropriate adjacent digit.

```
¶*[RL]

1
01
+`10
011
%`1
```

Remove left-over characters and convert from binary to decimal.

Comment: Hi, you have to output all numbers from `1` to `n`. Not just the `n`'th number.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Bah, there goes my sub-100 byte count...

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 98 bytes

```ruby
->n,r{t=->a{r ?a:a.reverse};(1..n).map{|k|i=0;t[t[k.to_s(2).chars].map{|d|d*(i+=1)}].join.to_i 2}}
```

Comment: Is the space at the ternary `a{r ?a:a.reverse}` necessary?

Comment: Yes. Ruby methods can end with `?`, `r?` would have been interpreted as a method name.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation. Never programmed in Ruby, but it looked like a regular ternary-if I use in Java (or C#), hence my comment.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>130</s> 127 bytes

*3 bytes, thanks Kevin*

I sure don't know enough ES6 for this site, but I tried! Loop through each number, and loop through each binary representation for that number, repeating each character however many times needed.

```js
d=>n=>{i=0;while(i++<n){b=i.toString(2),s="",k=-1,l=b.length;while(++k<l)s+=b[k].repeat(d?k+1:l-k);console.log(parseInt(s,2))}}
```

```js
f=d=>n=>{i=0;while(i++<n){b=i.toString(2),s="",k=-1,l=b.length;while(++k<l)s+=b[k].repeat(d?k+1:l-k);console.log(parseInt(s,2))}}
f(1)(10)
f(0)(10)
```

Comment: +1 from me. :) I think you can save a byte by using a currying input (`d=>n=>`), like the other two JS ES6 answers did. Also, I think you can save another 2 bytes by changing `k=-1,l=b.length;while(++k<l)s+=b[k].repeat(d?k+1:l-k);` to `k=0,l=b.length;while(k<l)s+=b[k++].repeat(d?k:l+~k);` (starting `k=0` instead of `-1`, and the `l-k-1` which is then required is shortened to `l+~k`). Also, are the parenthesis around the `(i).toString(2)` required?

Comment: The `+~k` seems like it should work, but I can't figure it out, keeps getting mad.  Thanks for the other tips!

Comment: Ah oops, `l+~k` is incorrect, since it isn't `l-k-1` but `l-k+1`.. My bad. You can still golf one byte by starting `k` on zero though: `k=0,l=b.length;while(k<l)s+=b[k++].repeat(d?k:l-k+1);`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 136 bytes

Lambda (curried) from `Boolean` to a consumer of `Integer`. The boolean parameter indicates whether to stretch left (values `true`, `false`). Output is printed to standard out, separated by newlines, with a trailing newline.

```java
l->n->{for(int i=0,o,c,d,s=0;i++<n;System.out.println(o)){while(i>>s>0)s++;for(o=c=0;c++<s;)for(d=0;d++<(l?s-c+1:c);o|=i>>s-c&1)o<<=1;}}
```

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
l ->
    n -> {
        for (
            int i = 0, o, c, d, s = 0;
            i++ < n;
            System.out.println(o)
        ) {
            while (i >> s > 0)
                s++;
            for (o = c = 0; c++ < s; )
                for (
                    d = 0;
                    d++ < (l ? s - c + 1 : c);
                    o |= i >> s - c & 1
                )
                    o <<= 1;
        }
    }
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jZAxa8MwEIXn5FeIDEXCtrDXyFahhUKHQiFj6aDKsqNUkYR0Tgmpf7srp5naDNl0p/c97r2dOIjCeWV37efkhw@jJZJGxIhehLbotFz4oA8CFIogIH3uEkAH0IZ2g5WgnaVPl0f94JxRwubXRI/OxmGvQv1sQfUqcI56BRsICuT2Nei0DaiZTMFtwU@dCzitkG7K3OUyb/PYlExnWW3Z5hhB7akbgPqZMxY7Qk5fW20U1pxHXpKYZWz2cI1MnExcZGRetGls04jNfSxkVq0lYe67mbFC3lXE1XVTsXGcFmyZsv8Wcol@cLpF@1QLTmdr27@9IxH6SOaWFleuWhnVQYLPEdcrwpLsX2YqvDdHDGFQhAoplQdclWftNcug@@2tnp0w8a/puBynHw)

### Limits

Because they're accumulated in `int`s, outputs are limited to 31 bits. As a result, inputs are limited to 7 bits, so the maximum input the program supports is 127.

### Explanation

This solution builds up each stretched number using bitwise operations. The outer loop iterates `i` over the numbers to be stretched, from 1 to *n*, and prints the stretched value after each iteration.

The inner `while` loop increments `s` to the number of bits in `i`, and the subsequent `for` iterates `c` over each bit position. Within that loop, `d` counts up to the number of times to repeat the current bit, which depends on input `l`. At each step, `o` is shifted left and the appropriate bit of `i` is masked off and OR'd in.